# Why we use 'log' in Vyper?

Tags: logs, vyper

What is the usage of the log? I want to get some examples of why 'log' is used in vyper

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to solidity's emit, usually placed at the end of a function to log an event.

Consider this excerpt from a rewrite of the weth9 contract.

```py
event Transfer:
  src: indexed(address)
  dst: indexed(address)
  wad: uint256 
    
@external
def transfer(dst: address, wad: uint256) -> bool:
  # NOTE: vyper does not allow underflows
  # so the following subtraction would revert on insufficient balance
  self.balanceOf[msg.sender] -= wad
  self.balanceOf[dst] += wad
  log Transfer(msg.sender, dst, wad)
  return True
```

[vWETH.vy](https://github.com/0xMaka/vybes/blob/main/vWETH.vy)

Looking at the log of the transaction we can see source, destination and amount transferred have been emitted and logged by the explorer: [image: weth transfer.]

Events are usually used by dapps to update front ends, or as a cheap form of storage.

You can read more about them in vyper specifically here:
https://docs.vyperlang.org/en/v0.3.9/event-logging.html